# Storing data in TEE of Android Device

Tags: android

I need to securely store data for an Android app in Trusted Execution Environment of the device. Is there any API for the same in Android? Is Android Keystore uses TEE. Could any one help me on this pointing to any references. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on the device greatly. Android Keystore can use the TEE for certain type of keys.

Refer to:

- [KeyInfo.isInsideSecureHardware()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/KeyInfo.html#isInsideSecureHardware%28%29)
- https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=3033.

For arbitrary data storage, you can:

1. Find out what secure keystorage options you have on your device
2. Encrypt data with the key of your choice
3. Store the secure key in your TEE and the Encrypted data in the device (nonTEE) area

Answer (score 0):

it depends. Android 7.0 intorduced Key Attestation, which could tell you if KeyStore stored in TEE or not. Based on the [official webpage](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-key-attestation.html) as of today not many device supports it (read note filed in the link).

Also a great article on this topic with examples for TEE usage: http://www.cs.ru.nl/~joeri/papers/spsm14.pdf